# Setting the Panel Owner

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, uicomponents

I've got an application that allows a panel to popup to allow the user to edit some properties.

How do I set the panel owner so that it is on top of all the other components on the page without actually disabling them like you do with an alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PopUpManager to display something on top of everything else.  I used a function like this to create the Popup before:

```
protected function createPopUp(className:Class):void{
  var win : IFlexDisplayObject = PopUpManager.createPopUp(Application.application as DisplayObject, className, false) as IFlexDisplayObject;
  PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
}
```

You can see it in action with the [Flextras Calendar API Explorer](http://www.flextras.com/Calendar/Samples/APIExplorer/).  Click any button on the top bar.

Comment: Thanks!

Couldnt actually find the code in th API source, but the demo told me it was what I wanted, and trial and error got me the solution. 


:-)

Comment: Glad it helped!  For future readers, the code in the demo is in the com.flextras.apiExplorer.Features.mxml file.